# Pause Javascript when executing it in browser console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, delay, sleep

I need to execute a Javascript in the console of Chrome with some delay. How can this be done?

The reason I need this is that as soon the focus changes from the webpage (or a certain element of the webpage) it is redrawn. Therefore I want to start the script I execute in the console with a few seconds delay so I can change the focus to the right element on the page I am working with.

Edit 1: Dinesh Padiyan.

Doesn't work for me, se screen shot:

[image]

Comment: You better use a debugger to walk through the code.

Comment: Have you tried putting `debugger;` statement at the point you want to enforce the execution halt? See more info here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/jsref_debugger.asp

Comment: I think that `debugger;` will stop all javascript from being executed.

Comment: You need to use double quotes . I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: The line should be `console.log("I won't execute until you say so")`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function delay (ms){   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, s));  }
```

"async" working demo on:
http://zarsoft.info/software/_Test/pause_javascript/index.html

Answer (score 7):

If you need to delay for debugging purposes, you will need to add `debugger;` statements to your code. When you add debugger and have your developer tools open, script execution will pause at your `debugger;` statement and you can inspect your code in the developer tools.

```
console.log('I will execute');
debugger; // execution will pause at this line
console.log("I won't execute until you say so");
```

If you need to delay execution for your site behavior, you can use `setTimeout()` to delay invocation.

```js
console.log('I will be printed immediately');
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('I will be printed after 5s');
}, 5000); // 5s delay
```

Answer (score 4):

You can extend `console` object like this and then use custom `logLater` method.

[image]

```js
console.logLater = (message, delay) => setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(message);
}, delay);

console.log('I will be printed immediately');

console.logLater('I will be printed after 3 seconds', 3000);
```

Comment: How do I use your example with something like `document.activeElement` ?